# Artifact and pixelation issue with baking vertex colors

Tags: materials, shaders, baking, vertex-colors

I'm trying to bake the red and green channels of a shader material using vertex colors, but the resulting solid mesh shows a lot of artifacts and overall doesn't look correct.

First screenshot shows the correct shading in Material Preview Mode:

[image: First screenshot shows the correct shading in Material Preview Mode]

Second screenshot shows the issues with the baked version in Solid Mode:

[image: Second screenshot shows the issues with the baked version in Solid Mode]

Anyone know why it doesn't look similar to what's in Material Preview?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you disable rendering on any other objects you're not using in the scene, also, apply, the scale to your object just in case, it seems you have some negative scales

Comment: Not disabling other objects in the render was the issue! Disabled them and the bake looks good. Thanks!